# Bulk import images into Firebase Storage and add download link to Firebase Database node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have about 1,000 image assets which I want to add to Firebase Storage (these assets are like product images/product variation images for a product page).

By adding the corresponding download image link into the appropriate node within Firebase Database, users are able to retrieve the image on their app.

I can manually go into Firebase Storage -> image path -> image and copy the download link, them add it to the Firebase Database node. However doing this over 1,000+ assets is not feasible. Does anyone know how I can achieve this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after much research. best solution was to get storage somewhere else (i.e. Amazon S3), store there, and upload links to fb in proper node.